# Longer Than Usual

Tags: knowledge, visual, geography, letters, chemistry

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/)</sub>

---

One for my fellow mapheads and pub quiz fans... There are many puzzles on PSE which use one-or-two-letter abbreviations to create coded messages - using, for example, [country ISO codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes), [US state abbreviations](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._postal_abbreviations), [UK postcodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postcode_areas_in_the_United_Kingdom), or [the Periodic Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_elements). However, often we find ourselves quite limited in the messages we can create via these means, as their alphabets simply do not give much scope for a message of any real length or complexity.

In that vein, my question to you today is: **What do you get if you combine two or more of these data sources?** Use the images below to help you figure out the **12-letter answer** (or, hang on, is it a 2-letter answer?!).

This puzzle *will* require much looking-up of information (use the links provided) or a good head for trivia. *You have been TUNGSTEN-ARGENTINA-NORTHLONDON-ERAWALED...*

[image: Map of the world with certain countries labelled with numbers]

[image: Map of the US with certain states labelled with numbers]

[image: Map of UK postcodes with certain postcodes replaced with numbers]

[image: Periodic Table with certain elements labelled with numbers]

Comment: In the [words of Randall](https://xkcd.com/1631/), maybe I should just go to bed...

Comment: UK postcodes? That's a new one. (For the record: This puzzle is Epic.)

Comment: Congratulations Stiv on surpassing 100k in shorter than usual time.

Comment: Thanks Tom :) I'm glad to have been able to contribute to this brilliant and creative community - I've learned a lot while here, and I'm still learning daily!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**What do you get if you combine two or more of these data sources?**

You get:

> **EXTENDED PLAY (EP)** !!!

---

By marking the correct code on each map, ([World](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcSYi.png), [US](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfvXP.png), [UK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dQGa.png), [Periodic Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9KiR.png)) we see that each number from 1-131 has its own unique code.

Putting them in a table, and reversing the code for red numbers:

> [image]
>
> We can see this is actually a list of more elements, states, postcode areas and countries, some backwards (marked with a †):
>
> **XENON†, TELLURIUM†, ERITREA, ANGUILLA, PORTSMOUTH, HAWAII†, ETHIOPIA†, NORWAY,  TRURO†, HYDROGEN, OLDHAM†, NITROGEN, DOMINICAN REPUBLIC, NEODYMIUM, LEICESTER†, WASHINGTON†, ARGON, MAINE†, URANIUM, IDAHO, ST ALBANS, LANCASTER, PENNSYLVANIA, MASSACHUSETTS, BATH, LAOS, YTTRIUM, TRINIDAD AND TOBAGO, RHODE ISLAND, MAURITIUS†**

Next,

> Taking the appropriate code, and reversing if backwards, we get:
>
>  **EX ET ER AI PO IH TE NO RT H LO N DO ND EL AW AR EM U ID AL LA PA MA BA LA Y TT RI UM**

And guess what? We have to do the same again! This list hides:

> **EXETER, ETHIOPIA†, NORTH LONDON, DELAWARE, PALLADIUM†, ALABAMA†, YTTRIUM**
>
> So now, once again taking the appropriate code:
>
> **EX TE N DE DP LA Y**

We get the final answer:

> **EXTENDED PLAY** or to abbreviate, **EP**!!
>
> Which fits the title, as an EP is 'Longer than usual'!

Comment: You beat me by 8 minutes on a 60 minute write up! Nice job :)

Comment: @cap wow close one! The writeup was certainly fiddly :P

Comment: Great job working your way through this one :) Hopefully you enjoyed this 'longer than usual' puzzle!

Comment: @Stiv I did very much so, and congrats on 100k!!!! Couldn’t be more deserved and hope to see 100 more for you :)

Answer (score 11):

This puzzle is definitely longer than usual. The reason is because it is an

> EXTENDED PLAY or EP

We start by following the instructions and gathering all the letters:

> Blue numbers mean take the letters in order. Red mirrored numbers mean reverse the letters.
>
>  1        NO
>  2        NE
>  3        XM
>  4        U
>  5        Ir
>  6        UL
>  7        LE
>  8        Te
>  9        RI
>  10       TR
>  11       EA
>  12       aN
>  13       GU
>  14       IL
>  15       LA
>  16       Po
>  17       RT
>  18       S
>  19       Mo
>  20       UT
>  21       HI
>  22       IA
>  23       WA
>  24       HA
>  25       IP
>  26       OI
>  27       hT
>  28       EN
>  29       OR
>  30       WA
>  31       YO
>  32       RU
>  33       RT
>  34       H
>  35       YD
>  36       RO
>  37       Ge
>  38       nM
>  39       AH
>  40       DL
>  41       oN
>  42       IT
>  43       RO
>  44       GE
>  45       N
>  46       DO
>  47       MI
>  48       NI
>  49       CA
>  50       nR
>  51       E
>  52       Pu
>  53       BL
>  54       IC
>  55       NE
>  56       OD
>  57       Y
>  58       MI
>  59       UM
>  60       rE
>  61       Ts
>  62       EC
>  63       IE
>  64       LN
>  65       OT
>  66       GN
>  67       IH
>  68       sA
>  69       W
>  70       Ar
>  71       gO
>  72       NE
>  73       NI
>  74       AM
>  75       uR
>  76       AN
>  77       I
>  78       UM
>  79       I
>  80       DA
>  81       HO
>  82       ST
>  83       Al
>  84       Ba
>  85       nS
>  86       LA
>  87       NC
>  88       AS
>  89       TE
>  90       rP
>  91       eN
>  92       NS
>  93       YL
>  94       VA
>  95       Ni
>  96       Am
>  97       AS
>  98       SA
>  99       CH
>  100      US
>  101      E
>  102      TT
>  103      Sb
>  104      At
>  105      H
>  106      La
>  107      O
>  108      SY
>  109      TT
>  110      RI
>  111      U
>  112      Mt
>  113      RI
>  114      nI
>  115      DA
>  116      DA
>  117      ND
>  118      TO
>  119      B
>  120      Ag
>  121      OR
>  122      Ho
>  123      DE
>  124      iS
>  125      LA
>  126      Nd
>  127      SU
>  128      iT
>  129      Ir
>  130      UA
>  131      M

The letters form a long string. We can

> break the string down like so:
>  NONEX MUIrULLET eRITREA aNGUILLA PoRTSMoUTH IIAWAH AIPOIhTE NORWAY ORURT HYDROGen MAHDLo NITROGEN DOMINICAn REPuBLIC NEODYMIUM rETsECIEL NOTGNIHsAW ArgON ENIAM uRANIUM IDAHO ST AlBanS LANCASTEr PeNNSYLVANiA mASSACHUSETTS bAtH LaOS YTTRIUM tRInIDAD AND TOBAgO RHoDE iSLANd SUiTIrUAM

Then we again

> Find two letter codes for each of the items. Reversed words get reversed symbols:
>  NONEX            eX
>  MUIrULLET        eT
>  eRITREA          ER
>  aNGUILLA     AI
>  PoRTSMoUTH       PO
>  IIAWAH           IH
>  AIPOIhTE     TE
>  NORWAY           NO
>  ORURT            RT
>  HYDROGen     H
>  MAHDLo           LO
>  NITROGEN     N
>  DOMINICAn REPuBLIC   DO
>  NEODYMIUM        Nd
>  rETsECIEL        EL
>  NOTGNIHsAW       AW
>  ArgON            Ar
>  ENIAM            EM
>  uRANIUM          U
>  IDAHO            ID
>  ST AlBanS        AL
>  LANCASTEr        LA
>  PeNNSYLVANiA     PA
>  mASSACHUSETTS        MA
>  bAtH         BA
>  LaOS         LA
>  YTTRIUM          Y
>  tRInIDAD AND TOBAgO  TT
>  RHoDE iSLANd     RI
>  SUiTIrUAM        UM

Then we

> break that string down: eXeTER AIPOIHTE NORTH LONDON dELAWArE MUIDALLAP AMABALA YTTRIUM

And do the same thing:

> eXeTER       EX
>  AIPOIHTE TE
>  NORTH LONDON N
>  dELAWArE DE
>  MUIDALLAP    dP
>  AMABALA      LA
>  YTTRIUM      Y

And we get our answer:

> EXTENDED PLAY

Comment: Nice work cap :) Always a shame to get pipped to the post after such a lot of work, but well done for seeing it through to the end!